# how to calculate button click count

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs

```
let clickStream = Observable.fromEvent(button,'click');
clickStream.scan( count => count + 1,0)
        .subscribe( count => console.log(`you click count is${count}!`));
```

this is angular2 project i'm use rxjs version is 5.0 , but count is object so it can't to calculate sum , how i to calculate count when button click?  this is log error ↓

Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '{}' and 'number'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is down to TypeScript not not matching the [overload](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.1/src/operator/scan.ts#L6-L8) you expect it to match.

If you explicitly specify the type for `count`, it should match the correct overload and the error should not be effected:

```ts
let clickStream = Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');
clickStream
  .scan((count: number) => count + 1, 0)
  .subscribe(count => console.log(`your click count is ${count}!`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, from my project:

```
 let clicks = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
 let ones = clicks.mapTo(1);
 let seed = 0;
 let count = ones.scan((acc, one) => acc + one, seed);
 count.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

dont forget to import these operators

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/scan';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mapTo';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
```